# How to find out the content of a XML file using Unix Sed/Awk?

Tags: unix, xml-parsing, sed, awk

I have a XML file(MyXML.xml) like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns3:GetAllInfoFromRest xmlns:ns2="http://com.lanuk.cfe/b2_7/service/objects" xmlns:ns3="http://com.lanuk.cfe/b2_7/service/operations">
            1111,GH43567,Hamburger,GET,278598655,\n000001,                    ,Kunal,Bhyuo,Ramond,856 K. 98 Rd,                                        ,                                        ,Tripura,AGT,INDIA,856987,                    ,S,S,S,8956,\666666
        </ns3:GetAllInfoFromRest>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Now i need to strip out the SOAP content and all the tag attributes from this xml and get only the string response `1111,GH43567,Hamburger,GET,278598655,\n000001,                    ,Kunal,Bhyuo,Ramond,856 K. 98 Rd,                                        ,                                        ,Tripura,AGT,INDIA,856987,                    ,S,S,S,8956,\666666`.

How can i do it with `awk` or  `sed` ?

I tried it in this  way :

```
$ xgawk -lxml 'XMLATTR["xmlns:ns3"]=="http://com.lanuk.cfe/b2_7/service/operations"{print $2}' MyXML.xml
```

But obviously I am making some mistake  due to which it is not working. 
Can some one suggest any other way around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk '{gsub(/<[^>]*>/,"")}NF{$1=$1;print}' file.xml
1111,GH43567,Hamburger,GET,278598655,\n000001, ,Kunal,Bhyuo,Ramond,856 K. 98 Rd, , ,Tripura,AGT,INDIA,856987, ,S,S,S,8956,\666666
```

`gsub` section replace everything starting with `<` and ends with `>`, so eks `<S:Body> is removed.` `NF` just print out lines that do contain data, removing blank lines. `$1=$1` removed leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Can you please give explanation for the above answer . It will help me in understanding what is happening .

Comment: Thanks for the explaino. However, i have one doubt , if everything within `<>` is removed, will it not also remove the string we are trying to get from the xml ?

Comment: No, normal tags are marked with start `<` and stop `>`, like this `<tag>`.  In xml, data should not be within `<>`, and data should not contain `<>`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into xmlstarlet (http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).
xmlstarlet is a command line xml toolkit. xmlstarlet allows you to convert
the xml into the pyx format.
pyx is essentially a flattened xml representation, one line per tag.
Then you can use grep, sed, etc. to extract what you want.